# C# connect to System ODBC datasource

Tags: c#, odbc, denodo

The server admin created a 32-bit ODBC system DSN for me that has the database and user credentials in it.  I'm struggling now to understand how to connect to that database from my C# code.  If I'm using an SSIS connection it goes through without issue, so I know the data they set is correct.

Am I supposed to be using SqlConnection or OleDbConnection to access this now?  I've tried both, and no matter what type of connection strings I try it always results in errors.  This is connecting to a Denodo instance of that matters for the connection string.

Comment: You should use OdbcConnection and related classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put in the DSN name that's been configured:

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=SAMPLE_ISAM");
// Your code here
DbConnection.Close();
```

Everything else is the same, the "Connection String" information is all contained in the DSN itself, if properly configured.

Comment: what if it is hosted on azure, then we can not use this way with DNS=something

Comment: Then this probably may not apply to you. Azure can require a different syntax anyway.